# Is it possible to invoke a host operating system's command line from a guest operating system?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

If I were running a Windows 7 virtual machine on an Ubuntu host, would it be possible to invoke the Ubuntu command line from Windows? I'd like to run the command "firefox http://facebook.com" from Windows (so that the host Ubuntu system opens facebook.com in Firefox.)

Comment: This question addresses the inverse question (for Virtualbox): http://superuser.com/questions/502579/invoke-guest-operating-system-shell-from-host-operating-system-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You should be able to do that with an `rsh` (remote shell) utility under Windows, connecting to an rsh daemon on Ubuntu.  Though I can't haven't tried it myself to speak to its quality, here's a sample [port from Netkit](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/bchafy/rsh_vista.html) that you might like.  Another alternative, as suggested below, would be [`putty`](http://www.putty.org/).

Comment: Or you know.  Use **SSH** (plink/putty) which has replaced RSH pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @Zoredache Do you know of any decent tutorials for SSH?

Comment: Also, is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035764/running-command-on-remote-machine-using-ssh

Comment: @Zoredache, good suggestion.

Comment: @AndersonGreen There is some decent material on the putty website and IIRC it has help files that explain (to some extent) how to use the program.