# Invoke guest operating system shell from host operating system (in Virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox

Using Virtualbox, is it possible to execute a shell command on the guest operating system from the host operating system? I'd like to create a script that runs the command `firefox http://www.google.com` on a Linux guest machine (from a Windows host machine.)

Comment: It appears that it's possible to do this on Linux (for a Linux host and a Windows guest): http://seechrisblog.com/2010/06/21/making-virtualbox-more-seamless/

Comment: You can use sshd on linux guest and ssh client putty.exe on windows host, but it requires network between host and guest.

Comment: @week Could you use this command to run a program from a Linux guest on a Windows host? `"VBoxManage guestcontrol execute "Windows XP" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" --username windowsusername`

Comment: That URL is broken, but luckily the page is archived: http://wayback.archive.org/web/20140210180433/http://seechrisblog.com/2010/06/21/making-virtualbox-more-seamless.